# Flex Box Whitespace Issue (Right Side)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, whitespace, spacing

I'm having some issues making this flex box span 100% of the width of the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/yfhbuwc3/

`<html></html>`

On the right hand side is whitespace (I have no idea where it's coming from)

I've tried making the width of the container 100% I've tried setting it to calc(100% + Xpx) but that doesn't calculate the spacing right and makes the box on the bottom right cut off the page on smaller screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're setting `flex-basis: 48%;` on `.top-row` which means each `.top-row` will only take `48%` of the screen. Since you want them to take the whole screen therefore `100/2 = 50%` so set `flex-basis` to `50%`.

And for the `.bottom-row`, you are setting it to `flex-basis: 32%;`, therefore `100/3 = 33.3333333333%` so set `flex-basis` to `33.3333333333%`.

```css
#grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.top-row {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 300px;
}

.bottom-row {
    flex-basis: 33.3333333333%;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#top-left {
    background-color: pink;
}

#top-right {
    background-color: red;
}

#bottom-left {
    background-color: orange;
}

#bottom-center {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#bottom-right {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid-container">
            <div class="top-row" id="top-left"></div>
            <div class="top-row" id="top-right"></div>

            <div class="bottom-row" id="bottom-left"></div>
            <div class="bottom-row" id="bottom-center"></div>
            <div class="bottom-row" id="bottom-right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I recommend learning more about [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) in general.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS-styles seem to be incomplete. When you are using `flex-basis`, you also should define `flex-grow` and/or `flex-shrink`. These properties are defining, how the elements will behave based on their flex-basis.

Please try it like this:

```
.top-row {
    flex-basis: 48%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 300px;
}

.bottom-row {
    flex-basis: 32%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: To be more efficent, it's better to adjust the [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) itself from the documentation: *The `flex-basis` CSS property sets the **initial main size** of a flex item. It sets the size of the content box unless otherwise set with [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).* See my answer.

Comment: You are right. Still, I wanted to answer the question based on the given values, since we don't have any context, if the flex-basis-values have to be fixed like this because of conventions we have no knowledge of.

Answer (score 0):

it is just **margin** property you need to set.
Add below code in your css.

```
 *{
      box-sizing:0px;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
    }
```